# how to configure syncevolution to access notes (text files) on owncloud server as evolution memo?

Tags: gnome, cloud, evolution

I wonder whether it can work, and if so how, to get evolution's view on memos to show notes (simple text files in a particular folder "Notes") on an owncloud server.

I run owncloud 9 and think of using syncevolution.

states a configuration [template](https://syncevolution.org/documentation/syncevolution-usage) exists, providing for "memo: plain text notes".

My attempt is

```
syncevolution --configure  --template webdav  syncURL=https://owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Notes  username=USER  "password=PASS"  target-config@owncloud

syncevolution --configure database=https://owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Notes backend=memo target-config@owncloud owncloudnotes

syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client sync=none syncURL=local://@owncloud username= password= owncloud

syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=memo database= owncloud owncloudnotes

syncevolution --sync slow owncloud owncloudnotes
```

The error I get is "database not found".

However, the URL is the one I use via another webdav client successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of sources suggest that syncevolution actually does not expect plain text files for memos but, much rather, expects caldavjournal/vjournal entries. 
I verified this using

```
syncevolution --print-databases   syncURL=https://owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Notes  username=USER "password=PASS"
```

the result is that at this address synevolution cannot detect anything...

Checking with

```
 syncevolution --print-databases   syncURL=https://owncloud/remote.php/dav  username=USER "password=PASS"
```

does provide positive results, showing all the carddav and caldav entries on the server. there are no caldavjournal entries.
A related question then could be how to create caldavjournal entries with owncloud, but that would also require to research available clients beyond evolution to read these entries. Gnome's Note application expects owncloud notes at the subfolder Notes on the owncloud account. But I will leave this for another time.

So, my resolution is that my question cannot be answered positively.